# How to find and replace for multiple occurrence in a cell contents in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the following values in a cell. That has to be replaced with some other value that will be fetched from another workbook.

```
sku=5777705,size=Large|sku=5777704,size=Medium|sku=5777706,size=XL
```

Here, the sku should be fetched from another workbook. The replaced sku will be,

```
sku id    sku name
5777705 107299710-5777705
5777706 107299711-5777706
5777704 107299708-5777704
```

So the output should be,

```
sku=107299710-5777705,size=Large|sku=107299708-5777704,size=Medium|sku=107299711-5777706,size=XL
```

So the sku id need to be replaced with sku name. How can I do that?

-Thanks

Comment: uhhh, **CTRL+H** for Find & Replace?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have 4000 records like this. Sometimes I have to replace for more than 20 occurrence in a cell.

Comment: I can see that there might be hundreds of different strings that need replacing, so it does look quite challenging in that case (or maybe there are only three different ones?). So the question to OP is, how many sku id/sku name combinations are there in the second workbook?

Comment: 58 thousand records i have in another sheet.

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: No, it is not an vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you workbook with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> open VBA. There in **VBAProject(** your workbook name **)** right click > Insert > Module.

Copy and paste this function there:

```
Function REPLACERANGE(celltoreplace As String, rangecodes As Range)
Dim y As Variant, a As String
    For Each y In rangecodes.Columns(1).Cells
            If celltoreplace Like "*" & y & "*" Then
                a = Application.Substitute(celltoreplace, y, Application.VLookup(y, rangecodes, 2, 0))
                celltoreplace = a
            End If
    Next y
REPLACERANGE = a
End Function
```

Then use the function in your file:

```
=REPLACERANGE(D1,A1:B4)
```

[image]

Comment: As you said, I just opened the vba and created new module. After applying the formula, the column value says "#NAME?" Am I missed anything?

Comment: That error is because the workbook is no finding the function. It depends where you create the Module. It has to be a standard module in the workbook.

Comment: Here is the file if you want to compare: [filelink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbmmxErUBYWWmGeN-kg3mql2yffIcdSf/view?usp=sharing) don't use google spreadsheets to open the file.

Comment: This has not been applied for all the rows. Some of the rows output is coming like "#VALUE!"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166153/discussion-between-virtualdvid-and-ts-guhan).